# **AttributeError: 'NoneType' error. An issue with BS

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to run this code using beautifulsoup, but I get the following error:

**AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'**

Here are the code lines:

```
pageSoup = soup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser')
pages = pageSoup.find('span',  {'class', 'textual-pager text-muted'}).text.strip()

-break-
```

Comment: The `.find()` method didn't find anything, so it returned `None`, and then you tried to access the `.text` attribute of it.

Comment: Please show us the full code that you have tried.

Comment: Also, `{'class', ` should instead be `{'class': `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the given exception error `find()` is returning `None`, which doesn't have any `text` attribute. [BS documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find) says `find()` will return `None` when it can't find anything.

I'd say it has something to do with the syntax you are using. What about trying `pages = pageSoup.find('span', attrs={'class': 'textual-pager text-muted'}).text.strip()` or `pages = pageSoup.find('span', class_='textual-pager text-muted').text.strip()`? Maybe you will get better results.

Comment: No, unfortunately the error persists with your both suggestions. Thank you anyways.

Comment: Do you get any results by trying `select()` method? Like: `pages = pageSoup.select('span.textual-pager.text-muted').text.strip()`

According to documentation:

`If you want to search for tags that match two or more CSS classes, you should use a CSS selector:`